# SQL querying on temporary tables takes double time compared to source Tables. Is that normal?

Tags: mysql, database, caching, query-optimization, temp-tables

I thought that a temporary table should be faster than a regular table, since I understand temporary tables are stored in cache and regular tables on-disk. But please correct me if I am wrong. Either way, if that is not the case, a temporary table is slower than the regular table from which it is an exact copy (of the data) and I would like to understand why.

I created a table with 100 million rows and 6 columns. Then I created a temporary table with all that data (a exact copy of that same table). But when I try a specific query on the original table it takes 23 seconds, as opposed to 1 minute of the exact same query on the temporary table.

So obviously, my understanding of "Temporary tables get stored on cache so they must be faster" is wrong. Could you please help me to understand why a temporary table having the same data as a regular table is slower?--- ¿How do they get stored? ¿Does MySQL uses a different engine for temporary tables? ¿Does the optimizer act different for temporary tables? ¿Do regular table get automatic indexes/partitions that temporary table don't get? ¿Any other reasons?

For the record, here is the normal table:

```
CREATE TABLE tablota (ALGO int, id_col int PRIMARY KEY,
col1 float NOT NULL, col2 float NOT NULL, 
tipo int NOT NULL,fecha TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

Here I am loading it from a ~8GB csv file (Note that the field "fecha" I had to use a non-standard format):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/generador.csv"
INTO TABLE tablota
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ALGO,id_col,col1,col2,tipo, @fecha)
SET fecha = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p');
```

Result is a 100,000,000 entries with 6 columns table (If I run `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tablota` the result is 100M). Then I create the temporary table as an exact copy (at least on data terms) of the original table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tablota_virt 
SELECT * FROM tablota;
```

And finally, here is the query on the "regular-table":

```
SELECT SUM(col1) FROM tablota WHERE tipo BETWEEN 1750 AND 1800;
```

Which, running it several times (more than 10 times) and with no other applications open on the server (Localhost, so my own PC), it takes 20-30 seconds. This query went with the full table scan plan.

And here is the query on the temporary table:

```
SELECT SUM(col1) FROM tablota_virt WHERE tipo BETWEEN 1750 AND 1800;
```

Which in same conditions (only MYSQL running and at least 10 trials), it takes 50-70 seconds. It also used full table-scan.

**EDIT:** The `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablota` gets:

[image: For tablota]

And for tablota_virt (the temporary one)

[image: For tablota_virt]

---

*For the record, I know that this is definitely not the best way to go while trying to optimize queries, I am aware that the first approaches should be selecting a correct data-schema, correct indexes and on the correct order, as well as partitioning. What I am trying to do here is purely testing temporary vs "regular" tables with no indexing, partitioning, concurrency of other queries, or other applications running in the server (my PC).*

Comment: Not a complete answer, but from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) it is clear that temporary tables, at least when fairly large, may also be stored on disks with regular tables.  So your notion that querying a temp table should be faster may be incorrect.

Comment: Don't forget to add indexes to your temporary table, especially if it's large.

Comment: And it's not obvious to me that partitions would help here.

Comment: Please provide the version of mysql (temp tables have changed) and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: I am running MySQL 8.0.23 with the InnoDB version 8.0.23. When i show the temporary tables (with `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO `) i get 'Name:#sql177c_a_17; NCols:9; SPACE:4243767290'. That i assume is the temporary table, because running that command before the ´CREATE TEMPORARY STATEMENT' I don't get anything. And lastly, the 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' i added it on the main question

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr. Temporary and permanent tables are the same kind of database object. The only things that differ in a temp table the naming scope (connection-local) and the automatic drop upon disconnection.

You wrote:

> I thought that a temporary table should be faster than a regular table, since I understand temporary tables are stored in cache and regular tables on-disk. But please correct me if I am wrong..

You are indeed wrong.

The query you showed us needs a compound index on `(tipo, col1)` to be most efficient. That is true whether the table is temporary or not. You should not expect large temp tables to have significantly better performance than ordinary tables.

Your query performance numbers probably depend on what happens to be in your server's RAM cache when you do the queries.  **Edit** It's impossible to know exactly what is in your server's RAM cache at any particular time. To the InnoDB engine, **the temporary table and the permanent one are more-or-less the same**. They are just two large on-disk tables it has to handle. I *think* your question assumes your newly created temp table should be in cache. The operation of writing rows into any InnoDB table, temp or perm, requires them to to be committed to disk. So, the server may use its cache for the permanent table's pages, not the temp one. Again, you can't know.

You could try creating an index on your temporary table. But, what a waste! You'll make your server do all the work of indexing the temp table just to drop it when you're done.

There's nothing much to be gained from creating such a large temporary table in the first place. Temporary tables use the same storage engines as ordinary tables unless you specify otherwise when you create them. They just have connection-scoped names, and get dropped when the connection closes.

You could use the MEMORY storage engine for the temporary table, but that will maybe use up your server RAM and fail. And at any rate the HASH indexes used by MEMORY tables are not optimal for the sort of range query you showed us.

My suggestion: rethink your workflow to get rid of the temporary table, and index your permanent table to match the queries where you need performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand that indexing/partitioning would be the best way to go. But I just want to understand why temporary tables that get in cache are twice as slow as regular tables when they both used the InnoDB engine. If it may guide more, I saw that when i ran the create temporary statement the RAM usage on my PC increased in 2.5GB of memory (even though the pure csv was 8GB), and I had 90% of free RAM (24 GB is what i have) before the statement. Is that a signal that it got into cache?

Comment: It's good to try to understand. Please see my edit. But please keep this in mind: MySQL (along with other databases) has been under development for more than a quarter century by many developers, and the way it handles its internal page caches is critical to its performance. Its caching probably doesn't work the way you guess it works.